# Binding behavior of ng-repeat track by

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets assume I am binding one big nested object to the $scope of the view shown in the code. Now, the value of an "e" object is updated. This would cause angular the check all bindings and update the DOM. If I used "track by" instead, in each ng-repeat directive, would that mean that only the binding for the "e" object would react and the dom for the "e" object be updated?

```
<div ng-repeat="a in b">
    <div ng-repeat="c in a">
        <div ng-repeat="d in c">
            <div ng-repeat="e in d">
                   {{e.value}}<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindings will be checked no matter what, and updated only if different, per the digest cycle. As for re-building the DOM elements, Angular uses unique identifiers to determine whether each item in an `ng-repeat` already has a matching DOM element, or if it needs to render a new one.

By default, Angular creates and manages these unique identifiers under the hood, using the `$id` of each object (or `$$hashKey`).

`track by` was added later, as a way to tell Angular to use a unique identifier of your choice, rather than managing it under the hood.

This is useful when updating the data removes/changes the `$id` or `$$hashKey`, triggering unnecessary re-builds of each DOM element, even when the data didn't change at all.

Consider this example:

- You have an ngRepeat which displays data records:

  `<li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.value}}</li>`
- You use a service `DataService` to update your data, which has a `fetch()` method which retrieves data from an SQL database, and returns the records.
- Updating the data in your `$scope` involves calling that service, and re-assigning your data variable to the result:

  `$scope.data = DataService.fetch();`

That means, even if only one item was different, all the `$id` or `$$hashKey` properties are gone or different, and Angular will assume all items are new. It will re-build all the DOM elements from scratch.

However, since your data is from an SQL database, you already have a unique identifier (primary key), the `id` column. You could then change your ngRepeat to be:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id">{{item.value}}</li>
```

Now, instead of looking for `$$hashKey`, which gets lost every time you re-assign the data, Angular will use the property you told it to (`item.id`). Since that property *does* persist across re-assigning the variable, the list is once again optimized, because Angular will only re-build DOM elements for new `item`s.

Comment: Thanks, so this means that by using "track by" I can have a view of deeply nested ng-repeat directives without significant performance loss if a single element of the underlying data structure changes making a view update (DOM rebuilding) necessary. Are there still any quirks to watch out for?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Though you should still try to optimize what gets marshalled by data services, because even if the DOM is optimized, the data gathering might not be (n+1 queries, etc). As for quirks, the only one I can think of is that it doesn't always play nicely with filters or orderBy. They can work (put them _before_ the `track by`), but it ends up being much safer and cleaner if you handle them on the controller using $orderBy.